# Crashlytics iOS crashes upon start 'Object reference not set'

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a shared Xamarin app for iOS and Android. At the moment I'm getting it Firebase Crashlytics, I've alread installed and it's mostly working. However when I try to add the bit of code in charge of sending the iOS reports to crashlytics, the app crashes on startup with:

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. Callstack: '  at app.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00007] in C:\Users\user\source\repos\app\app.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:28 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.xamarin_UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr,intptr&)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (System.Int32 argc, System.String[] argv, System.IntPtr principalClassName, System.IntPtr delegateClassName) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.5/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.Type principalClass, System.Type delegateClass) [0x0003b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.2.0.5/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:92 
  at diarioDeTeruelIOS.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\user\source\repos\app\app.iOS\Main.cs:14 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:395 '
The app has been terminated.
```

I've made sure every thing is in order in the instalation up to this point. Following the same [tutorial](https://medium.com/@freakyali/firebase-crashlytics-for-maui-and-xamarin-19938cc24f81) and other resources I've made the Android side of things work. However iOS keeps on crashing. This only happens when using Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics classes/methods, Firebase.iOS.Core ones don't present any problem.
AppDelegate.cs :

```
namespace app.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Initializer.Initialize();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

                Crashlytics.SharedInstance.Init();
                Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SetCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                Crashlytics.SharedInstance.SendUnsentReports();
            /*
             * 
             */


            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm working on visual studio 2022 and .NET Standard 2.1 my debugging devie is a phisical device (iPhone 7 I think).

Comment: Which is the problematic line?

Comment: Also, which packages did you add to your project and versions of these?

Comment: @Cheesebaron
The problematic lines are those with `Crashlytics.SharedInstance`
I added the NuGets for: xamarin.iOS.Core (8.10.0.3), and xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Crashlytics (8.10.0.3)

Comment: It can only be one of them if your App crashes?

Comment: @Cheesebaron i'm preety sure it would be `Chraslytics.SharedInstance.Init()` since the others can't work without it. I've tried to run the app with each line individually and all make the thing break down.

Comment: May I know your exact VS version and iPhone version? What if you send the report via another physical device like iPhone 14? Also, there's a [demo project](https://github.com/FreakyAli/FBCrashlytics) that demonstrates the setup process, you can give a try.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I'm using an iPhone 7, iOS 15.7.1 (I don't have any other iPhone avalible an can't update this iPhone's iOS) and i'm using Visual studio community 2022 17.5.3 I've already checked that demo a bunch of times to no avail.